# iOS Accessibility - Change AccessibilityElementsHidden without delay?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uikit, accessibility, voiceover

I am working on a view in which certain elements will be removed and re-added as accessible items depending on the state of the view. I have been able to successfully achieve the functionality I desire by setting `AccessibilityElementsHidden` to toggle the state.

However, I am finding that there is a brief pause (~1-2 seconds) between this field being set before the Accessibility Layout is updated, which can allow the user to highlight a deactivated accessibility element if they are moving at a reasonable pace. If they are focused on an item as it is being disabled it makes it difficult to re-orient oneself in the VoiceOver interface.

I have found methods to immediately update the display of the interface (by means of `SetNeedsLayout()` and `LayoutIfNeeded()` on the main thread) but unfortunately this does not trigger the Accessibility Layout update.

I have also tried using `UIAccessibilityPostNotification.LayoutChanged` but like the changing of the `AccessibilityElementsHidden` property, this also takes a moment to propagate to the view.

Can anyone provide some insight as to what I need to do to ensure the user cannot put themselves in a bad state before the Accessible Layout is applied?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing same problem. Also, even after Accessibility Layout is updated after ~1-2 seconds making all accessibility elements disabled, if user swipes left or right with single finger, VoiceOver starts focusing deactivated accessibility elements on left and right of last focused element.

Comment: @Maverick I'm afraid I have not yet. I will let you know if I do.

Comment: Good afternoon. Anyone has managed to find the solution for that issue? I am facing it right now. Cheers.